Exception MysqlDataTruncation when parsing a String 1899-12-30
public Timestamp convertFromDate(String fromDate) throws ParseException {
        String[] possibleFormats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
        ParseException lastException = null;

        for (String format : possibleFormats) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                dateFormat.setLenient(false);
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(fromDate);
                return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                lastException = e;
            }
        }
        throw lastException;
    }

This is the code which i am using to parse a string in possible Timestamp format but when it pass through each it gets parsed but generates a Timestamp for example for a string 1899-12-30 to 1899-12-30 00:00:00.0  this .0 is causing an error. Which format or what change do i make to this code to make it work?
Basically I am concerned about this parsing. The other logic for saving is done by calling Spring Boot respository where the parsed date is set to the object and then the repository save method is called, from where the exception is generated. I know this is the method causing me the error which is generating the wrong timestamp format.

Your code works just fine for me. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss doesn't throw any exception when the string 1899-12-30 00:00:00.0 is supplied to the method. However, if your string contains milliseconds, and you wanna make sure to parse them, then you need to include the millisecond group as well SSS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html Also, I don't know the scope of your program, but you might wanna take a look to the java.time library https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Do you have to use Timestamp, Date and SimpleDateFormat? They are considered notoriously troublesome and de facto outdated. You could use java.time instead…

but be aware that using S or SSS (@dani-vta)  means milliseconds and 1899-12-30 00:00:00.1 would mean 1 millisecond after midnight (0.001)  and not 100 milliseconds (0.100) - one more reason to stop using these outdated classes, replaced by classes in the java.time package in Java 8 (10 years ago)

You want something much more like: DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().optionalStart().appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").optionalEnd().optionalStart().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").optionalEnd().parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0).optionalStart().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").optionalEnd().parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0).parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0).toFormatter(); LocalDateTime ldt =  LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf);

I just want to get the without any milliseconds, i am passing string getting from the csv column and then it should be passed to each possible format a return 1899-12-30 00:00:00

My code will give you 1899-12-30T:00:00 from input "1899-12-30" (which is actually correct for the minimal output of a zero-timed LocalDateTime)

Sounds like you want to format the resulting Timestamp… You can do that with another SimpleDateFormat outside that convertFromDate where the error occurs. See this post…

If you're using a Timestamp I assume you're using it with JDBC, so the likelihood that you'd need to format it (legitimately) is very remote. Use the type (which has no format as it's not a String) as is with your JDBC code You could return that type with something like return new Timestamp(LocalDateTime.parse("1899-12-30", dtf).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli());

For your sanity’s sake stop immediately using Date, Timestamp and SimpleDateFormat. Those classes were troublesome and are fortunately longoutdated, supplanted by java.time, the modern Java date and time API, more than 10 years ago.

Back when we used Timestamp -- which was before the advent of database drivers supporting JDBC 4.2 -- its toString method produced strings in the format like 1899-12-30 00:00:00.0. Are you saying that the trailing .0 in this string is causing an error somewhere else in your program? You can’t rewrite that toString method, but as many have said, you can and should stop using Timestamp.

What exactly is the data type of your column in the database? What is your database engine? Are you trying to record a moment, a specific point on the timeline?

As I mentioned earlier, Timestamp doesn't have a format (unless it becomes a String) so unless you're using it as a String (and you almost certainly shouldn't be) then it can't really cause an error

What does this code have to do with MySQL? How did you get a MysqlDataTruncation exception with no JDBC code?

Voting to close, as this Question has too many missing details to make sense.

basically i am concerned about this parsing the other logic for saving is done by calling spring boot respository where the parsed date is set to the object and then the repository save method is called from where the exception is generated i know this is the method causing me the error which is generating the wrong timestamp format.

@IbrahimAlvi java.sql.Timestamp has no “format” as it has no text. So your Comment does not make sense.  Also, java.sql.Timestamp is a terribly-flawed legacy class that should be avoided.

@IbrahimAlvi Thanks for clarifying your concern and thereby the question. What you know is wrong, though. As more people have said already, a Timestamp (repeating myself, a class that you should not use) hasn’t got any format. And in particular not any wrong format. So it simply is not possible that its format is causing your error. Perhaps your use of a Timestamp object is in itself causing the error. From what you have posted we cannot know.

Does this answer your question? Is there a simple way to change a timestamp value containing seconds and ms to a timestamp value having hours and minutes? Does this?

Does this answer your question?

You Question makes no sense. Your title claims a MysqlDataTruncation exception, but your code does not involve MySQL nor JDBC. I can respond in part, specifically to your code snippet.
Regarding the code snippet, you have two major problems:

You ignoring crucial issue of time zone. Your results will be inconsistent, varying by the JVM’s current default time zone.
You are using terribly-flawed date time classes that are now legacy, having been supplanted long ago by the java.time classes defined in JSR 310.

JDBC 4.2 and later requires every JDBC driver to support the java.time types. Never use the classes Timestamp, Date, Calendar, SimpleDateFormat, etc. Use only java.time.
Regarding parsing, I would first check the length of string.

10 characters means one of our two date-only formats.
19 characters means a date-with-time format.
Any other length means invalid input.

For the 10-character length, check for the presence of slash or hyphen character to parse as a LocalDate. For the slashes, define a formatting pattern with DateTimeFormatter class. Your other format complies with ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes by default use the standard formats. So no need to define a formatting pattern, just parse directly.
For the 19-character length, swap the SPACE character in the middle for a T to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. Then parse as a LocalDateTime object.
For our date-only, I assume you want to default to the time 00:00 as we derive a LocalDateTime object from our LocalDate object.
But neither a LocalDate nor LocalDateTime object represents a moment. I assume you want a moment, a point on the timeline, though you did not specify one way or the other.
For a moment, we need a third part. We need the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC to determine a moment. I will assume you meant the offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. This offset is represented by the constant ZoneOffset.UTC.
We can apply ZoneOffset.UTC to our LocalDateTime object to generate a OffsetDateTime object. At this point we are ready to submit this value to a SQL database column of a type akin to the SQL standard type of TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.
If you don’t want the fraction of a second, truncate.
String input = "23/01/2025";

// Represent a moment in `OffsetDateTime` for recording in a SQL database column of
// a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
OffsetDateTime odt = null;
// We expect only 3 possible input string formats:
// Date-only;  "YYYY-MM-DD" or "DD/MM/YYYY".
// Date-with-Time:  "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".  (lacks offset or zone)
long countCodePoints = input.codePoints ( ).count ( );
if ( countCodePoints == 10 )
{
    DateTimeFormatter f =
            input.contains ( "/" )
                    ? DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
                    : DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
    odt = ld.atStartOfDay ( ).atOffset ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
}
else if ( countCodePoints == 19 )
{
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input.replace ( " " , "T" ) );
    odt = ldt.atOffset ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
}
else
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "Invalid date string submitted. Must be either 10 or 19 characters." );
}
odt = odt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
// myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;

All of this has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.
